# VBA IE click/show javascript with no id or tag not a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

How to use VBA to click/show javascript with no id or tag on a website?

I am using Excel 2010 with these references:
Visual Basic for Applications

Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library

OLE Automation

Microsoft Office 14.0 Ojbect Library

Microsoft HTML Object Library

Microsoft Internet Controls

There is text "Show details" in a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped cols20 schedule-table" id="container-no-1-1">
<colgroup>...</colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="container-row">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="hidden-print">
        <a title="Details to be displayed after Gate in full move" data-url="/trackingapp/transportplan?equipmentNo=ABCD1234567&amp;shipmentId=60G0KZBCBKY5C" class="pull-right show-toggle with-icon" data-target="#more_info_1_1" href="#more_info_1_1" data-toggle-text="Hide details"><i class="icon-expand"></i>"Show details"
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

href.click does nothing:

```
Dim ObjIE As Object
Set ObjIE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
ObjIE.navigate "www.whatever.com"
ObjIE.Visible = True
Do While ObjIE.Busy Or ObjIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
For Each objLink In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HREF")
 If objLink.href ="#more_info_1_1" Then
  objLink.Click
  Exit For
 End If
Next objLink
```

Neither does putting a URL in a string:

```
Dim myURl As string, myString As String
myString = "ABCD1234567"
myURL = "http://www.whatever.com/search?searchNumber=" & myString
IE.navigate myURL
```

However, once the "Show details" is clicked by user interaction, the HTML is:

```
<table class="table table-striped cols20 schedule-table" id="container-no-1-1">
 <colgroup>...</colgroup>
<tbody><tr class="container-row">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>        
    <td class="hidden-print">
        <a title="Details to be displayed after Gate in full move" data-url="/trackingapp/transportplan?equipmentNo=ABCD1234567&amp;shipmentId=60G0KZBCBKY5C" class="pull-right show-toggle with-icon" data-target="#more_info_1_1" href="#more_info_1_1" data-toggle-text="Hide details"><i class="icon-collapse"></i>Hide details</a>
     </td>
         <td class="hidden-print">
            <a title="Details to be displayed after Gate in full move" data-url="/trackingapp/transportplan?equipmentNo=ABCD1234567&amp;shipmentId=60G0KZBCBKY5C" class="pull-right show-toggle with-icon" data-target="#more_info_1_1" href="#more_info_1_1" data-toggle-text="Hide details">
                <i class="icon-collapse"></i>
                    Hide details
            </a>
        </td>                                       
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="show loaded" id="more_info_1_1">
<div class="row transport-plan-details" style="margin-left: 0;">
    ::before
<div class="offset1 transport-plan location-detail well well-white margin20right">
    <h4 class="location">
        <span class=""></span>
        "Singapore"
    </h4>
    <table class="row container-move past transport-plan-tbl cols20">
        ::before
        <colgroup>....</colgroup>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <i class="icon-GATE-OUT-EMPTY"> 
                    ::before
                </i>
            </td>
            <td>
                "15 Feb 2016"
                    <br>
                    16:47"
            </td>
            <td>
                <strong>Gate out, empty</strong>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        ::after
    </table>
```

So, I am looking for a way to click "Show details" and then return "Singapore", "15 Feb 2016", "16:47", and "Gate out, empty" in VBA.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer. since the source html file only have one  element. you can use document.getElementsByTagname("a")(0) to get the element.
like below:

```
set myEle=document.getElementsByTagname("a")(0)
myEle.click
Do While ObjIE.Busy Or ObjIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

the same, you can find the number of `td` and `strong` and get
their `innerText`

or you can try to get the data from http request to capture the data.

```
    url = "http://www.whatever.com/trackingapp/transportplan?equipmentNo=ABCD1234567&amp;shipmentId=60G0KZBCBKY5C"

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "referer", "http://www.whatever.com"
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.send

    result = XMLHTTP.responseText
    result = trim(result)
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
```

After you capture the html to the variable, you can use `instr`,`mid` to cut the variable.

If it is also not ok, you can try to use webquery to capture the data.

Comment: Thank you, Kenneth. But myEle.click does not show the hidden content and does not return anything.

Comment: Hi ninja, 
1. Have you test that `myEle` are currently map to the current <a> item.
2. since the link is to another file, Are you sure that don't require some cookie or session variable.

Comment: by the way, I wonder why you don't directly open the target link instead of opening a link and also call a click action.

Comment: Thank you, Kenneth. Using the string url to directly open the target link returns a search-error page. Also, I think the string starting "60GOKZ..." appears to be random per search. I'll look at your suggestions of cookie and session variables.